# How to close the standAlonePlayer of youtube API after the completion of video

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am trying to play youtube videos using StandAlonePlayer. Which is working fine. But I want to close the player after completion of video. How to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

here is my code to play video using standalone player.

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(context, Consts.DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID,0,true,false);
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

On activity result I can handle the error state. But I want close the player once video completes.

Answer (score 0):

If the video is in a VideoView,so you can call setOnCompletionListener to it so you will be notified that the video is done playing.

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.stop();
       //write your code after complete video play  
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not using any views for this. StandAlonePlayer will take care of it. No need to use any View if we use StandAlonePlayer.